# Ubuntu-Mate-Welcome cannot open applications.json

Tags: 18.04, python, ubuntu-mate, json

Ubuntu 18.04

When I run Ubuntu-Mate-Welcome I get this error and the software boutique never populates.

```
IndexError: list index out of range

[Apps] Software Index JSON is invalid or missing! 

[Apps] /usr/share/ubuntu-mate-welcome/js/applications.json
```

The json file is there and it validates with jsonlint.

I have tried both the apt and snap versions and they do the same.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using Ubuntu or Ubuntu Mate?

Comment: @WalterZAMBOTTI so you've  tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software center.?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu Mate.  I am posting in their forum as well.   Tried uninstalling ubuntu-mate-welcome both snap and apt and reinstalling just the apt version in case of conflict.